# Problema con CLI en CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, cli

Estoy intentando ejecutar CLI siguiendo la [documentación](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/cli.html) pero me arroja errores y no hay manera.

Estoy situado en la raíz principal de mi proyecto, uno vacío con un par de métodos en welcome.php y conexión a una base de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La configuración previa mínima que tengo es:

`$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');`

`$config['uri_protocol']    = isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ? 'PATH_INFO' : 'CLI';`

Función que llamo:

```
public function test_country($country)
{
    $this->load->library('unit_test');
    $actual = $country;
    $expected = 'Japan';
    $name = 'Existe pais recibido';
    $this->unit->run($actual, $expected, $name);
    echo $this->unit->report().PHP_EOL;
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Esta claro que tienes mal la configuración de tu base de datos.
Puedes probar

Cambiar de

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

a

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('');
```

Y si necesitas la base de datos, revisar el archivo database.php para ver que tenga la configuración correcta.

"Unable to connect to a database using the provided settings."

Aparece por esa misma razón.

Tus soluciones son como dije antes:
1: desactivar el autoload de database (para que no se conecte en todas las pantallas a la base de datos y puedas usar el cli).
2: Conectarlo a una base de datos correcta, para eso tendrías que poner los datos de tu database.php para ver si eso tiene algún error.